# NP inference explanation

Tags: np-complete

I've been taking a look at the following question and came up with some answers but I'm wondering if there's more to it.

The Question is as follows:

Assume that there are proofs for the following four statments. Can you infer anything about A, B, C, and D? Explain your answer.

a) X is a polynomially solvable problem and A is polynomial reducible to X.

b) X is an NP-Hard problem and B is polynomially reducible to X.

c) X is a polynomially solvable problem and X is polynomially reducible to C.

d) X is an NP-Hard problem and X is polynomially reducible to D.

My Answers:

a) We can infer that since X is at least as hard as A and is polynomially solvable then A is polynomially solvable.

b) We can only infer that B is at most as hard as an NP-Hard problem.

c) We can infer that C is polynomially solvable as well. this is because if c was not polynomially solvable then X would not be either and would contradict the given proof.

d) We can infer that D is at least as hard as an NP-Hard problem (making it be in NP-Hard space). If we knew that it was in NP then we could say that it's also NP-Complete but we do not know.

Comment: Your conclusions of a) and c) look awfully similar considering that the hypotheses are fundamentally different.

Comment: @ErickWong shouldn't they be due to transitivity ?

Comment: transitivity of what?  In a) you have $A \le X$ and in c) you have $X \le C$, which is exactly the reverse.

Comment: my mistake, not transitivity. I'm positive that a) is a correct statement. I would say c) is true because of the contradiction stated above

Comment: a) sounds good, but I think it would help if you go into more detail about why X is not polynomially solvable for c).